# Json error on Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I need some help finding out what's wrong in this code:

```
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "http://localhost:8181/add", true)
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajaxRequest.send(data);
```

I'm trying to send data to the server using POST, and ajaxRequest is an `ajaxRequestElement()`.

The problem is when I open the page, the console provided by Chrome to detect Javascript errors says `POST http://localhost:8181/add undefined (undefined)`.

I know the URL is correct and the page receiving the data is ok too, I tried this before in PHP and works fine, so I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: try either 'http://localhost:8181/add' on your url section or simply just 'add'

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are posting to http://localhost/add instead of http://localhost:8181/add.   Could you simply use 'add' as the url to post your ajax request to?

Comment: Sorry, I typoed that. Anyway, I tried both ways with the same results =(.